# MongoDB - Can I loop through a set of rows, sum other rows based on the first rows, then update my original rows in one command?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out if I can do this query with one MongoDB update/query command, or if I going to have to write a NodeJS function to do it with 2 or 3 queries.

Given this data from my client's design:
[image]

The pseudocode would be as follows:

1. Find each row where type="parent"
2. For each row from step 1, find all the rows where row.bay=currentRow.bay and row.toSku=currentRow.toSku and type="child" and sum up the "requires" column.
3. Take that summed number, and update the Step 1 currentRow.requiresExtended with that sum.

When done, the "requiresExtended" column should equal the value of the "requiresExtendedDesired" (which I computed manually for a simple test case). The 5 is the sum of 2+3, the 21 is the sum of just 21, the 203 is the sum of 101+102).

I see from here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/ that we can do updates from an Aggregate Pipeline.

I'm also studying examples here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/select-with-sub-query/115744/7

I want to add on more thought.  I don't mind using multiple commands, but if I do, can I pass those multiple commands to MongoDB together and get one result back?  If yes, then I'm looking at this example as well: [MongoDB - simple sub query example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304211/mongodb-simple-sub-query-example).  But then I have many questions there.  Like can you have a full query under a $lookup's "from" field.

This is my really crude start at trying something like the above StackOverflow describes.  I'm trying one stage at a time...
and I realized I couldn't use the localfield with the pipeline in the $lookup, so this is what I have up to now (this post helped also: [Pipeline in lookup aggregation not working in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157459/pipeline-in-lookup-aggregation-not-working-in-mongodb))

```
db.NealTestBay.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { type: "parent"},
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "NealTestBay",
            "let": { "toSku": "$toSku" },
            "pipeline": [
                 { "$match": {
                         "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$toSku", "$$toSku" ] }
                 }}
             ],
            "as": "grp"
        }
    }
])
```

Full  test data below:

```
{
  "RECORDS": [
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678b",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "5",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "parent"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678c",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "21",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part2",
      "type": "parent"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678d",
      "bay": "bay 2",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "203",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "parent"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678e",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "2",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "0",
      "sku": "X1",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "child"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678f",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "3",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "0",
      "sku": "X2",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "child"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa112000072006790",
      "bay": "bay 2",
      "requires": "101",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "0",
      "sku": "X2",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "child"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa112000072006792",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "21",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "0",
      "sku": "X4",
      "toSku": "Part2",
      "type": "child"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6336223aa112000072006793",
      "bay": "bay 2",
      "requires": "102",
      "requiresExtended": "0",
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "0",
      "sku": "X7",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "child"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To confirm, you are attempting to update _all_ `"type": "parent"` documents in the collection? Is this a one-time operation or something that you will be doing periodically/frequently? Any additional context regarding the functionality this would support would be really helpful in framing an answer.

Comment: @user20042973 I was asked by one of my part-time clients to look into this as their programmers couldn't figure it out.  For now, it's just a proof of concept, and I think it will be something that runs on a regular basis, but I don't have the full details.  And yes updating all "type": "parent" rows such the the "requiresExtended" value will match the "requiresExtendedDesired".  The "desired" field is just something I put there for illustration purposes, it won't be there after the prototype.

Comment: Okay.  The answer is 'yes' what you're asking for can generally be done, I'll try to write up an answer later. But they should probably seriously reconsider the schema. Why wouldn't the child documents just be embedded in the parent (and kept up to date when they are modified)? Probably much better long term.

Comment: @user20042973 I think it's a traditional Bill of Materials Structure.  They will probably want a common web page that updates any row of the table with the same screen and logic.  The real structure is of course much more complex than this, I had to simplify to get my head around it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: It's a "traditional Bill of Materials Structure" _for a normalized schema in a RDMBS system_.  But that's different than a BoM schema designed to be used in MongoDB. Specifically the `child` "rows" (documents) referenced in step two of your pseudocode almost certainly make sense to have as embedded documents in a `children` array on the single `parent` document. There is a reference for such one-to-many modeling [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: @user20042973 I will certainly show that to them, but they like to do their own design.

Comment: @user20042973 But that link is just 1 to many.  Have you used Bill of Materials before, it's one to many to many to many to many for many levels of depth.  A part can be made of other parts, which can be made up of other parts, which can be made up of other parts, etc...  I'm looking at this too: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/bill-of-material-data-modelling/118594

Comment: @user20042973 They are telling me they want more than parent/child, like a child can have a child, and that child can have a child... then I think we are into writing a solution in NodeJS.  Even the "type":"parent" didn't exist in their sample; I added that to help me understand and visualize the data better.  In their design, you know the parent by certain fields be blank or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MOp86srCrLw

Let's try with this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "Parents": [
        {
          "$match": {
            type: "parent"
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "k1": {
              "$concat": [
                "$toSku",
                "-",
                "$bay"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Children": [
        {
          "$match": {
            type: "child"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "$concat": [
                "$toSku",
                "-",
                "$bay"
              ]
            },
            "v": {
              "$sum": {
                "$toDouble": "$requires"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "k": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            k: 1
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Parents"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      index: "$Parents.k1"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Parents.requiresExtended": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {},
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "myVar": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$Children",
                    {
                      "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$Children.k",
                        "$Parents.k1"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "in": "$$myVar.v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      Parents: 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "Parents.k1": 0
    }
  }
])
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Parents": {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678b",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": 5,
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "5",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    "Parents": {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678c",
      "bay": "bay 1",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": 21,
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "21",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part2",
      "type": "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    "Parents": {
      "_id": "6336223aa11200007200678d",
      "bay": "bay 2",
      "requires": "0",
      "requiresExtended": 203,
      "requiresExtendedDesired": "203",
      "sku": "",
      "toSku": "Part1",
      "type": "parent"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That is one amazing query, much appreciated.  I will be studying it.  When I run it in Navicat, it produces 3 rows of output, each with a document of the three rows and the results.  Also, can I pipe all the above now into an update?

Comment: Yes, aggregate pipe can be used for update. In order to help studying:
1) $facet creates list of key, values pairs (used k and v in order to prepare them for $arrayToObject fn - didn't need it
2) $let  returns a value Children.k for a given Parents.k1 - k1 is a temp field used to create a mapping keys.