# mongodb combining $lookup and $match gives error "must contain exactly one field"

Tags: mongodb

When I run the $match by itself it works, and when I run the $lookup by itself it works.
Can I not combine these two? And would the "from" for the $lookup, not need to be the output of the $match somehow, instead of the original collection name.

```
db.NealTestBay.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { type: "parent"},
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "NealTestBay",
            "localField": "toSku", 
            "foreignField": "toSku",                        
            "as": "grp"
        }
    }
])
```

I'm getting this error when I combine them:

```
[Error] A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
at line 1, column 1
```

My full sample database and rows are in my more complex question here: [MongoDB - Can I loop through a set of rows, sum other rows based on the first rows, then update my original rows in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902540/mongodb-can-i-loop-through-a-set-of-rows-sum-other-rows-based-on-the-first-ro).  I'm trying to break it down into a series of pipeline stages.

So my first step is to find the rows with type="parent", then join them with the rows that have type="child" and have the same value for the field "toSku'.

I also tried using the "pipeline" under the $lookup, but it told me that it doesn't allow that a the same time you use "localField" and "foreignField".

Comment: its simple typo, you have wrong syntax, you need `[{$match},{$lookup}]` each stage in seperate document, fix that, and if you have still problems with somehting else, maybe update the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Takis comment, this seems to work:

```
db.NealTestBay.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { type: "parent"},
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "NealTestBay",
            "localField": "toSku", 
            "foreignField": "toSku",                        
            "as": "grp"
            }
    }
])
```

It wasn't so much as a typo, as just reading blogs and guessing what I'm doing.